# wrong value select option from database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I am creating update feature using laravel, I have tried to passing value to be updated but the value is failed or wrong.

Here's my sql table

```
id |    name        |            email                |     pic_for
1     Michael             michael@mic.com                    null
2     John Doe            john.doe@gmail.com                  1
3     Kelme               kelme@gmail.com                     2
4     Munich              x.munich@det.com                    1
5     Phylon              phy@phylon.com                      2
```

To show the value and changed it, I am using two statement in controller, users to get name user and pic for selected value

Here's my controller process

```
public function updateuser($id)
{
    $users=DB::table('users')->where('id',$id)->get();

    $pic=DB::table('users')->get();

    //dd($id);
    //dd($users);

    //menampilkan data ke view index
    return view('updateuser',['users'=>$users,'pic'=>$pic,'id'=>$id]);

}
```

Here's my view.blade

```
  @foreach($users as $user)                      
 <div class="row">
     <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT"> 
     <div class="col-md-12 pr-1">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label>Name</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" value="{{ $user->name }}">
          </div>
      </div>

  <div class="col-md-12 pr-1">
     <div class="form-group">
          <label>In Charge</label>

          <select name="in_charge" id="in_charge" >

           @foreach($pic as $pics)
               @if($pics->pic_for != null)
                 <option value="{{ $pics->pic_for}}" selected>{{ $pics->name }}</option>
               @else
               <option value="{{ $pics->id}}">{{ $pics->name }}</option>
               @endif
        @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
 </div>
 @endforeach
```

What I want is when admin click data user, it's shown like the database

```
 Name  ; name

 Pic   : pic_for
```

And admin can change the pic column using select option value where the value is taken from all id.

The Problem is in selected value, when I click or show the page, the select option get wrong value

```
What I Want
Name : John Doe (id 2)
Pic For : Michael (id 1) selected value
It has same value with database

For Now
Name : John Doe (id 2)
Pic For : Phylon (id 5) selected value
```

Do you know where error code ?

Thank you

Comment: where did you get the $id from? I don't see any input that's connected with it

Comment: Do you want all from `pic_for` column or just the ones whose != null , you can add in your query `->where('pic_for','!=',null)`

Comment: Hi @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din the $id from I get from $users in controller

Comment: HI @ViperTecPro, what I want is the data pic_for shown like the database and the admin can change user pic_for to another id

Comment: so  the problem in `$pic` collection? if so , please try this in the controller `dd($pic);` after fetching the data and post the output. if it's not the problem, please provide more details

Comment: Hi @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din, the probem is in selected value in view blade, I've tried your suggestion and it's shown all the id, which is I assume it's true, so I passed the value to view blade

Comment: Why are you using `$users=DB::table('users')->where('id',$id)->get();`  ? that always return collection of the model.. why not using  `$users=DB::table('users')->where('id',$id)->first();`  you can remove the first loop from the blade file.

Comment: You can remove both loops and you can write on a single line. Use.. https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line and try

```
@if($pics->id == $user->pic_for)
 <option value="{{ $pics->pic_for}}" selected>{{ $pics->name }}</option>
@else
```

You need to check the pic_for from users

Comment: Hi, I have tried your suggestion but I still get wrong value in selected area

Comment: `Example : Id 2 pic for id 5, it's wrong because id 2 should be pic for id 1`  what is your question???

Comment: What I want
**
Name : John Doe (id 2)
pic_for : Michael (id 1)
**
Have value same with database, 

For Now

Name : John Doe (id 2)
Pic For : Phylon (id 5)

Comment: Thanks shibon, I clearly understand where I was wrong

Comment: Hi @Shibon, how about checkbox ? I've modified based on select option code but it's getting wrong view

Answer (score 0):

You try this:

```
return view('updateuser',compact(['users']);
```

Comment: I have edited my code in the question, I have tried your suggestion 

return view('updateuser',compact(['users','pic']));

but it's not work

Comment: `return view('updateuser', compact('users', 'pic'));` should be work